# Mongod not working in terminal, trying to reassign alias

Tags: mongodb, macos, terminal

I am using Mac Monterey

When I type `mongod` in the terminal, I get the shutting down exitCode:100 error.

I can reassign `mongod` with `alias mongod="sudo mongod --dbpath /usr/local/data/db`, then mongod works after I type in my password, it does not work if I do not add sudo.

If I do not add sudo, I get the aborting after fassert() failure error.

After restarting the terminal, I have to reassign mongod again otherwise I get the exitCode:100 error again

I tried to re-assign `mongod` with `alias mongod="sudo mongod --dbpath /usr/local/data/db` in the .bash_profile file using vim.

Then `mongod` works, but only for that one session... if I restart the terminal, then I have to re-assign it again.

I tried re-assigning it in the .bash_profile... but I think I might be doing it wrong or something

can someone please help with this?

Comment: Why do you use an alias? Install it as a service (see https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/#run-mongodb-community-edition) then it will even start automatically when you start the computer.

Comment: Will keep that in mind next time, learning new things everyday, not sure if I want it to start every time I use my computer though, but I guess it also doesn't really matter if it does, not as if it uses a lot of resources. Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, all the comments on google says to use a .bash_profile to update the mongod file path, however I found that I was supposed to update the file path in a .zprofile file as I'm using zsh and not bash